# GNU screen when run in daemon mode, what happens if it receives a SIGTERM:

Tags: unix, process, parent-child, gnu-screen

I have a script that launches screen in daemon mode which in turn runs the program command.

```
screen -L -c <SCREEN_CONFIG-FILE> -dmS <SCREEN-NAME> <program-COMMAND>
```

The script will exit after launching screen.

When I do a ps, I see that both screen and program are running with different pgid and sid.
The ppid of the program is the screen~s pid.

Now if a SIGTERM is sent to  screen process, what happens to the program: will it get SIGTERM: in my experience, both screen and program got killed, however the program did not get the SIGTERM signal, it died because of some other signal I think.

Also, what happens if SIGTERM is sent to the program process directly or if the program exits itself, will the screen process will also die:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send SIGTERM to the screen daemon it will terminate and all child process will terminate as well. If you send the process of the command the SIGTERM it may depend on the command. Usually it should terminate as well, if it's some script you can edit you might be able to trap the SIGTERM and prevent it from being terminated.

Lets say your did something like this:

```
screen -dmS test-screen bash -c top (screen PID 2001 / top PID 3001)
```

and you say

```
kill 2001
```

the screen daemon will terminate and  with it the bash hosting top and top will be terminated too.

```
kill 3001
```

will terminate top, the bash will terminate and the screen daemon will end.

Comment: how is top terminated when SIGTERM is sent to 2001? will the SIGTERM propagate to top or is there any other signal that is sent to top? and in second case why will the screen daemon end, how exactly its accomplished i mean?

Comment: I noticed that when SIGTERM is sent to 2001, SIGTERM is not propogated to the program 3001, but still 3001 was killed, could screen killing the program process by SIGKILL or some other signal in this case: